# Releasing Grails database connection early

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails

I have a controller action that does the following things:

1. Gets a domain object from the database
2. Uses info on that object to find a data file (on disk) and writes contents of that file to the response output stream.

My problem is that the database connection is reserved for the duration of the action, including the (long) time required to stream the data. This results in a lot of unnecessary database connections when there are several users streaming data at the same time.

```
def stream() {
  StreamDetails sd = StreamDetails.get(params.id)

  // Extract info needed to read the stream
  String filename = sd.filename

  // The database connection is no longer needed, how to properly release it?

  // Start writing the data stream to response output
  // This may take a long time and does not use a db connection
  streamService.writeToOutput(filename,response.getOutputStream())
}
```

I have tried:

1. Injecting the `sessionFactory` bean to the controller and calling `sessionFactory.currentSession.close()` before calling the service. However this causes a `SessionException` on the line calling the service, ie. before entering the `writeToOutput()` method (and nothing in that method needs a database connection). AND I don't think the session should be really closed, just released to the pool.
2. Copy-pasting the code from `streamService.writeToOutput(...)` to the controller to avoid the service call. In this case all the code gets executed but a `SessionException` is still thrown after the action is complete.

How to properly release the connection early?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried to inject the dataSource? You could use the DataSourceUtils to create a new connection that you can then use to get the filename. You can then manually close() this connection.

I don't know if you can use this connection in combination with gorm, so you might have to create a custom sql query as well.

Comment: Close the _entire_ DataSource? Nope.

Comment: Ooops, of course not. I thought about a connection created with the dataSource. I have clarified this. But this solution is not the best anyway.

Comment: I got it working like this: use DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource) to get a connection, write custom sql statements and then close the connection after it is not needed. I had to copy-paste the output writing code into the controller, as calling a service method would create a db connection. Thanks for your help!